# Expresión de MATLAB a Python con sentencia if

Tags: python, matlab

Estoy pasando código a Python desde MATLAB. En una de las funciones me encuentro con:

`if sum(f_area) < 2, return, end`

La cosa que nunca he visto dicha expresión escrita así, entiendo que si el área fuera mayor de 2 ya no continuaría la función y se quedaría ahí. ¿Alguno puede iluminarme y a ser posible cómo podría escribir dicha sentencia en Python?

Comment: `if sum(f_area)<2: return` eso?

Comment: ya lo he probado, la cosa es que dudo que sea con return en Python ya que pone que debe devolver sí o sí un argumento. He probado también con continue y  tampoco.

Comment: El `return` se usa dentro de una función, si no hay una te dará error. No se nada de matlab,  que se supone que hace el código?

Comment: Si el área es menor que 2, el programa continúa por donde lo dejó, de no ser así, el programa pararía y saldría de la función.

Comment: Si pudieras agregar más código (de ambos lenguajes) sería bueno

Comment: creo que ya entendí, debería de ser `if sum(f_area)<2: exit()`

Comment: Sii también me vale! el problema es que estaba haciendo pruebas en un código que no era una función, por eso me daba error. Con exit() puedo hacerlo sin problemas.